# python program to reverse the list iterable problem

Tags: python, list

A list rotation consists of taking the first element and moving it to the end. For instance, if we rotate the list [1,2,3,4,5], we get [2,3,4,5,1]. If we rotate it again, we get [3,4,5,1,2].

Here are some examples to show how your function should work.

```
rotatelist([1,2,3,4,5],1)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]

rotatelist([1,2,3,4,5],3)
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]

rotatelist([1,2,3,4,5],12)
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

I tried to code it successfully but had a problem, when I concatenate the list, I get the error: int iterable error but when I use `append` the program executes successfully, kindly explain the concept here is my python code:

```
def rotatelist(l,k):
    if k<0:
        return l
    new_list=l[::]    
    while k>0:
        temp=new_list[0]
        new_list=new_list[1:]
        new_list=new_list+list(temp)
        k-=1
   return new_list
```

Comment: `list` takes an iterable as parameter, and you are passing it an `int`. Instead of `list(temp)`, you should write `[temp]` in order to get a list containing this unique value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code:

```
def rotatelist(l,k):
    if k<0:
        return l
    new_list=l[::]    
    while k>0:
        temp=new_list[0]
        new_list=new_list[1:]
        new_list.append(temp)
        k-=1
    return new_list
```

or this one:

```
def rotatelist(l,k):
    if k<0:
        return l
    new_list=l[::]    
    while k>0:
        temp=new_list[0]
        new_list=new_list[1:]
        new_list=new_list+[temp]
        k-=1
    return new_list
```

will produce the following output:

```
rotatelist([1,2,3,4,5],1)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]                                                                                                                                               

rotatelist([1,2,3,4,5],3)
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]                                                                                                                                               

rotatelist([1,2,3,4,5],12)
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

You have the error because you are trying to make a list with an integer:

```
temp = 1
print(list(temp))
```

output:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The example below works fine because you are putting an integer inside a list:

```
temp = 1
print([temp])
```

output:

```
[1]
```

Comment: why not to use list(temp) the list function also converts the items present in it as list

Comment: because you are trying to make a list with an integer. I have added 2 more examples in the answer.

Comment: ok i got it in list () we can only work on the iterable objects like strings,tuples,dict etc as int is non iterable we can not use in list() but we either make it list using [] or use append , thanks for your cooperation

Answer (score 1):

```
def rotatelist(l, n):
    n = n % len(l)
    return l[n:]  + l[:n]

print(rotatelist([1,2,3,4,5], 12))
```

Prints:

```
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import deque
d = deque([1,2,3,4,5])
d.rotate(-3)
Ouput:
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```

OR in your case

```
def rotatelist(l,k):
    if k<0:
        print(l)
    new_list=l[::]    
    while k>0:
        temp=new_list[0]
        new_list=new_list[1:]
        new_list=new_list+[temp]
        k-=1
    print(new_list)

rotatelist([1,2,3,4,5],3)
```

Output:

```
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: why not to use list(temp) the list function also converts the items present in it as list

Comment: @AnkushRasgon your `deque` example will not produce expected result - a negative number has to be used in `.rotate()`.

Comment: @PranavSharma [] just wraps temp in a list. list(temp) converts it to a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `deque` and its `rotate` method.

```
from collections import deque


def rotatelist(l, k):
    dq = deque(l)
    dq.rotate(-k)
    return list(dq)
```